# How to differentiate /dev/tty with stdin, stdout, stderr?

Tags: unix, python-3.x, console-application

I try this with Python3:

```
import os
fd = os.open('/dev/tty', os.O_RDWR|os.O_NOCTTY)
print(fd)
```

It always prints 3 in Linux. Is /dev/tty file descriptor always 3?

I want to differentiate /dev/tty with stdin,stdout,stderr. My initial attempt is to check the file descriptor since stdin,stdout,stderr return 0, 1, or 2.

The reason I am asking this is because to write to /dev/tty in Python, I have to use bytes not string while with stdin,stderr,stdout, I have to use string.

So my second attempt is:

```
try:
    if file.isatty() and file not in [sys.stdout,sys.stdin,sys.stderr]:
        use_bytes = True
    else:
        use_bytes = False
except AttributeError:
    use_bytes = False
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: When you call open you get a NEW file descriptor.  0, 1, 2 are already open when the process starts.  So 3 is a newly created file descriptor.  Use .fileno() on an existing file object to see the file descriptor number.

Comment: You mean this: import os; fd = os.open('/dev/tty', os.O_RDWR|os.O_NOCTTY); a = os.fdopen(fd, "wb+", buffering = 0); print('it is /dev/tty') if (a.fileno() == 3) else print('no, it is not /dev/tty')? So /dev/tty file descriptor UNDER ALL CIRCUMSTANCES will be 3 IN ALL UNIX PLATFORM?

Comment: No.  You missed the point. In UNIX, by default, ALWAYS: stdin == 0, stdout == 1, and stderr == 2.  Forget 3.  Three does not exist.  It is an artifact of your code.  What OS are you on?  If there is a /proc file system, you can see your open files for a process.  /dev/tty is a device (really a file), it is not a file descriptor. You make file descriptors (1,2,3,4...) when you open a file.  Do not open any files. Use fileno() on stdin, not /dev/tty.

Comment: I am on Linux. I think I understand your point. If my function accept the file object as the argument and we want to check whether this argument is a /dev/tty or not, I just make sure the fileno of the argument is not 0,1,2 and the file object is tty. Is that it?

Comment: /de/tty is the controlling terminal. That is the name of the controlling terminal device from INSIDE the process. isatty can return true for stdin, stdout, and stderr. Because all three have /dev/tty already open. Not all processes have a controlling terminal.